# Show that the expected value of a random variable that admits symmetric distribution is $0$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Consider $X_{1}$ is  a random variable that admits the symmetric distribution, that is $X_{1}=_{d}-X_{1}$ (or $\mathbb{P}(X_{1}>x)=\mathbb{P}(X_{1}<-x)\ \text{for all}\ x$) such that $\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>x)=x^{-2}$ for $x\geq 1$.

I'd like to show that $\mathbb{E}X_{1}=0$. I had some attempts but got stuck. To show this, recall that we have a lemma:

> for $p>0$, and $Y\geq 0$, we have $$\mathbb{E}Y^{p}=\int_{0}^{\infty}py^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(Y>y)dy.$$

Thus, $$\mathbb{E}X_{1}\leq|\mathbb{E}X_{1}|\leq\mathbb{E}|X_{1}|=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>x)dx.$$

However, the problem here is that $\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>x)=x^{-2}$ only for $x\geq 1$. So how could I compute the integral from $0$ to $\infty$?

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

I have some progress as follows:

As $x\mapsto\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>x)$ is a decreasing function, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>x)dx\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_{1}|>k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}=\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{6},$$ which is not helpful here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X\overset{d}{=}-X$, $\mathsf{E}X=\mathsf{E}(-X)=-\mathsf{E}X$ (the tail condition ensures that $X\in L^1$).

Comment: What do you mean by tail condition?

Comment: Also, if I also want to show  $EX^{2}=\infty$, what should I do here?

Comment: $\mathsf{P}(|X|>x)=x^{-2}$ for $x\ge 1$.

Comment: Why does this condition ensure $X\in L_{1}$?

Comment: $\mathsf{E}|X|\le 1 + \int_1^{\infty}x^{-2}dx=2$ and $\mathsf{E}X^2\ge \int_1^{\infty}x\times x^{-2}dx=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much :)